# Core graphics CGContextSetFillColorWithColor not filling my shape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I have the following shape which I need to fill with a color or a background image:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGMutablePathRef pPath_0 = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(pPath_0, NULL, 72.61 / 2 + xCoordinates,20.21 / 2 + yCoordinates);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pPath_0, NULL, 69.19 / 2 + xCoordinates,16.37 / 2 + yCoordinates);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pPath_0, NULL, 26.02 / 2 + xCoordinates,16.37 / 2 + yCoordinates);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pPath_0, NULL, 22.69 / 2 + xCoordinates,20.21 / 2 + yCoordinates);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pPath_0, NULL, 22.69 / 2 + xCoordinates,20.21 / 2 + yCoordinates,17.69 / 2 + xCoordinates,24.84 / 2 + yCoordinates,17.69 / 2 + xCoordinates,34.71 / 2 + yCoordinates);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pPath_0, NULL, 17.69 / 2 + xCoordinates,194.87 / 2 + yCoordinates);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pPath_0, NULL, 17.69 / 2 + xCoordinates,194.87 / 2 + yCoordinates,20.87 / 2 + xCoordinates,206.37 / 2 + yCoordinates,47.69 / 2 + xCoordinates,206.37 / 2 + yCoordinates);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pPath_0, NULL, 48.69 / 2 + xCoordinates,206.37 / 2 + yCoordinates);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pPath_0, NULL, 75.69 / 2 + xCoordinates,206.37 / 2 + yCoordinates,77.69 / 2 + xCoordinates,194.87 / 2 + yCoordinates,77.69 / 2 + xCoordinates,194.87 / 2 + yCoordinates);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pPath_0, NULL, 77.69 / 2 + xCoordinates,34.71 / 2 + yCoordinates);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pPath_0, NULL, 77.69 / 2 + xCoordinates,24.84 / 2 + yCoordinates,72.61 / 2 + xCoordinates,20.21 / 2 + yCoordinates,72.61 / 2 + xCoordinates,20.21 / 2 + yCoordinates);
CGPathCloseSubpath(pPath_0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,1.0000);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);
CGContextSetMiterLimit(context, 10.0000);

CGContextAddPath(context, pPath_0);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
CGPathRelease(pPath_0);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

I'm trying to use the following code to fill the shape with a red color but it doesn't work:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);` and `CGContextFillPath(context);` do the same thing. There's no reason to do both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it:

```
CGContextAddPath(context, pPath_0);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
CGPathRelease(pPath_0);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Comment: You could clean up your code a little bit by setting the stroke and fill colors and then just saying CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke). This will draw the path and then fill and stroke it using the colors specified.